# How can I implement a comparator to compare two numbers?

Tags: java, interface, boolean, comparator

I have a class `OffbyOne` where I declare an interface as a comparator called `compare` where I'm supposed to take two integers and return True if the difference between two integers is 1, and false if not.

Here is my code so far:

```
public static class OffbyOne {
        public interface Compare {
            int x;
            int y;
            if ((x-y) == 1) {
                return true;
            } else if ((y-x)==1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false
            public boolean equalChars(char x, char y); {
                if (Compare(x,y) == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

I'm struggling to understand how comparators work in Java and what do I have to do. If anyone can please help me with this and then provide explanations for how it is supposed to be done, it would be great for me.

Thank you.

Comment: comparators have 3 cases, when x > y then of `x - y` is greater 0, when x == y then exactly 0, otherwise it's smaller than 0. That's why the comparator interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) needs to return a number. i.e. checking for equality would be `if (Compare(x,y) ==0)`. You should probably just use Java's Comparator interface and the many utility functions it provides if you want to use it outside of study code. You also can't return values from an interface, like you do.

Comment: I think you would be better of just writing a method with name `isOffByOne`.

Comment: A Comparator is something that implements the [Comparator interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  It's difficult to make sense of what you're trying to do, since the code is syntactically invalid, and a method that determines if two integers differ by unity cannot be the basis for a Comparator anyway

Comment: ```public boolean isOffByOne (int x, int y) { return Math.abs(x - y) == 1; }```

Comment: @g00se I want to try and use comparators for this though

Comment: That's not appropriate

Comment: @accessviolation thats what im trying to understand right now and my code, which is wrong, is based off my understanding of it. Can you please show me how to implement it. Sorry about the messed up code, I'm really new so I'm prone to making mistakes

Comment: The job of a `Comparator` is to define an ordering - i.e., "does X come before Y?".  I can't see any way to use a method that computes "do X and Y differ by 1" in a Comparator.  For a start,, the result for your Compare(1,999) is the same as the result for Compare(999,1); if you somehow forced that into a Comparator, you'd apparently be claiming that 1 is before 999 and 999 is before 1.  So, which are you interested in achieving: using a Comparator, or having some "differ by one" method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparator already exists in java - `java.util.Comparator`. It is something *completely different* from what you describe: Java's own comparator is a thing that you give 2 objects, and the comparator tells you which of the two 'comes earlier' in a sorting. Such an oracle is all you need to efficiently sort stuff.

It's allowed, but a bad idea, to name types the same as core java types. You can make your own `String`, which is different from java's own `String` in all ways (your `String` does not in any way replace java's string), it's just a confusing name, is all. You're doing the same thing with `Comparator` here. Bad idea. I'd call it `OffByOne` or similar.

> declare an interface as a comparator called compare where I'm supposed to take two integers and return True if the difference between two integers is 1, and false if not.

This makes no sense whatsoever. You must have misunderstood the assignment. An interface describes the what **and does not describe the how**, whereas what you just said is describing the how. That's just not what interfaces do - they don't get to define the how. They only define the what. You're describing an implementation, not an interface.

> ```java
> public interface Compare {
>             int x;
>            int y;
>             if ((x-y) == 1) {
> ```

You can't stick code in types like this. You can stick only methods, fields, constructors, and other types in there. You can stick code in a method and then stick the method in a type, if you want. In addition, given that it is an interface, you can't stick code in one **at all** - interfaces define what a `class` can do, not how it does it (there is the `default` mechanism. That's definitely not what this assignments wants you to do so, so it doesn't apply here).

This would be an interface:

```
public interface DifferenceOfOne<T> {
  public boolean isDifferenceOfOne(T a, T B);
}
```

This says: There is such a thing as a 'DifferenceOfOne' implementation for any given type. Such a class would implement the method `isDifferenceOfOne`, which takes in 2 parameters, both of that given type, and which then returns a boolean.

You can then make an implementation for the Integer type:

```
class IntDiffOfOne implements DifferenceOfOne<Integer> {
  public boolean isDifferenceOfOne(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return (a - 1 == b || b - 1 == a);
  }
}

DifferenceOfOne<Integer> intDiffOfOne = new IntDiffOfOne();
```

Or in more common, modern java syntax:

```
DifferenceOfOne<Integer> intDiffOfOne = (a, b) -> (a - 1 == b || b - 1 == a);
```

And someone else can write a DiffOfOne implementation that, I dunno, tells you if any 2 `LocalDate` instances differ by exactly 1 day, perhaps, that would be a `DifferenceOfOne<LocalDate>`.

If this all sounds confusing to you - go back to whomever gave you this assignment, as either the assignment makes no sense, or you misheard/misunderstood it.

Comment: Thank you for taking ur time off to explain this concept to me! Really appreciate it!